# Compiler Error CS0029: "if (int & int)"

Tags: c#, boolean, int, implicit-conversion

Adapt the old code in C + +
The compiler does not pass the type expression "if (a & b)"

```
int a = 32;
int b = 1;
if (a & b) {} <--- Compiler Error
```

Implicit conversion from Int to Bool.
I can change to `if ((a & b)! = 0) {}`
But it is worse to read and found in many places.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: C# has stronger type rules than C++, and no implicit type conversions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Well, it has _some_ implicit type conversions.

Answer (score 5):

There is not it implicit conversion in C#. And `if` only accept boolean.

You have to do : `if ((a & b) != 0) {}`

Answer (score 3):

In C#, an `int` being non-zero does not evaluate to `true` automatically. An `int` is an `int` and not a `bool`, so `if (i)` only works if `i` is a `bool`.

Comment: Wait... `xyz != 0` *should* evaluate to `true` or `false`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Ah, now I understand where you were heading with that answer. +1

Comment: Yep, I misunderstood what you were saying too.  :)